# Cannot add a key to an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

## JavaScript #mongoDB #express #nodejs

I have an array of objects that I receive from a mongoDB.  After receiving the array of "areas" I want to **add** an key to each object in the array.  (The added key will be the localized fromat of a date value that will later be used when rendering the HTML page.)

```
// we are inside a express controller for a webapp here
var moment = require('moment');

exports.getAllAreas = function(req, res) {
  AreaModel.find().sort('-updatedAt').exec(function(err, allAreas) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log("area table data:\n%s", JSON.stringify(allAreas, null, '  '));
    for (var i = allAreas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      allAreas[i]['createdAt_View'] = moment(allAreas[i].createdAt).format('L');
    };
    console.log("area table data ###:\n%s", allAreas);
    res.json(allAreas);
  });
};
```

The data coming from mongoDB ("allAreas" array) is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56f0f7cdd99f646c99ad1e2f",
    "updatedAt": "2016-03-19T13:02:19.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-03-19T13:02:19.000Z",
    "description": "Very important topics",
    "title": "Another Area"
  },
  {
    "_id": "56f0f7eed99f646c99ad1e30",
    "updatedAt": "2016-03-01T13:02:19.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-01-19T13:02:19.000Z",
    "description": "Even more",
    "title": "Area2"
  }
]
```

My problem: After the for loop the allAreas array and its contents **are not changed at all!**

Some more sidenotes:
 - I use a (backward) for-loop instead of a .foreach clause, because this is faster.
 - "moment" is a JS library that can localize data values

Are mongoDB results somehow immutable in Javascript?
Am I missing something with by-value or by-reference here? I just don't find it.

---

**Solution** (credits got to @RayonDabre)

Mongoose (the OR-mapper that I use) returns a [Mongoose Document](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon-dabre) from the query. So the variable **allAreas** in the callback is actually a 'bigger' Javascript Object, that you cannot add properties to in this way.

When you add `.lean()` to the Mongoose Query Builder, then mongoose returns a plain javascript associative array, that you can add keys to.

Thanks to all stackoverflow members for helping so quickly!

Comment: Use `lean()` => `AreaModel.find().sort('-updatedAt').lean().exec(function(){...`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with the core logic you have. It might be something else like what @RayonDabre points out. Here is what I tried https://jsfiddle.net/g4aqytsf/

Comment: @Reddy, With `mongo`, things are different..Returned `object` is not really a JS object but a `MongooseDocument`

Comment: @RayonDabre I just knew mongo is a Database. And this problem might not be related to DB right?

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks for the info.

Comment: @RayonDabre   Thank you very much for the tips. Adding lean() solves my problem.